# rake aborted! cannot load such file -- ap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, web-deployment

I have build my new rails application and when I am trying to deploy to Apache server while executing `bundle exec rake secret` I am getting `rake aborted! cannot load such file -- ap`.This is the URL I have referred to deploy [Deploying a Ruby app on a Linux/Unix production server](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/apache/oss/xenial/deploy_app.html#rails_preparing-the-app-s-environment).

Please look into my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'json'
gem 'jenkins_api_client'
gem 'mailfactory'
gem 'docx','>=0.2.07'
# gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'net-scp'
gem 'rubyXL'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'bcrypt'
# font awsome
gem "font-awesome-rails"
# parsley validation
gem "parsley-rails"
# devise for athentication
gem 'devise'
# gem "devise_ldap_authenticatable"
gem "toastr-rails"
# datapciker
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
# image uploader
gem 'carrierwave'
# Active admin for admin
# gem 'activeadmin'
# To set dynamic value in docx
gem 'sablon'
# State_machine for status
gem 'aasm'
# Soft delete
gem 'paranoia'
# for seed
gem 'seed-fu'
# Net-SSH gem to exec batch file.
gem 'net-ssh'
# Schedule job
gem 'whenever', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem "awesome_print", require:"ap"
  # gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'pry-rails' 
  gem 'bullet' 
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

This is my first application i tried to deploy, please help to resolve this issue

My ruby version is

```
ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-linux]
rails version - 5.1.4
```

Comment: Link is broken in your post

Comment: Broken link is fixed. Thanks

Comment: If you are running rails for the first time on this server, first of all make sure it starts with native "rails server". Then, rails depends much on environmental variables, so make sure $PATH contains folder with ruby gems. Also, what about other rais/ruby commands on server? Doesn't seem like apache/fusion related stuff

Comment: Thanks @goose3228 I need to install server and need to deploy my rails application please refer me a URL to follow up. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in the Gemfile seems strange to me

```
gem "awesome_print", require:"ap"
```

Can you remove the `require: "ap"` and check if it works then?

Comment: I need to install server and need to deploy my rails application please refer me a URL to follow up. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at http://codepany.com/blog/rails-5-capistrano/ for example. Capistrano is a standard gem for rails deployment.